how to pasue execution for 1 second? Javascript
const wait = (n) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, n));

async function writeDescriptions(folderPath) {
    
    fs.readdir(folderPath, (err, files) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error reading folder:', err);
          return;
        }
     
        files.forEach(async (file) => {

          await wait(1000);
          
          const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
      
          fs.stat(filePath, (statErr, stats) => {
            if (statErr) {
              console.error('Error getting file stats:', statErr);
              return;
            }
            

            if (stats.isFile()) {     
                if(opisRegex.test(file)) {
                    writeFileToStorage('short_description/', file.slice(0, -7) + '.txt', filePath);
                } else {
                    writeFileToStorage('pictures/', file + '.jpg', filePath);
                }
            
            }
          });
        });
      });
}

I want to wait one second before every write to my backend storage. I tried with setTimeout, i tried with this implementation of wait(n), I tries with setTimeout from timers/promises and nothign works.
Can someone help me how to do it? I'm beginner in js.

files.forEach(async ... doesn't work well.  You need a for..of loop. see this

Please show what you tried that didn't work. setTimeout(function(){code that should run when timer is done},1000); should work.
